# Is there a way to get the total size of a 'BigInteger' variable?

Tags: java, biginteger

I would like to be able to tell how big in bits is a variable of type **BigInteger** in my program.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `bitLength()` ([source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/biginteger_bitlength.htm))

> The `java.math.BigInteger.bitLength()` returns the number of bits in the minimal two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger`, **excluding** a sign bit. For positive `BigIntegers`, this is equivalent to the number of bits in the ordinary binary representation.

```
BigInteger bi;
bi = new BigInteger("778674");
System.out.println("length: " + bi.bitLength());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I somehow missed `bitLength()` while looking for the available options.